# Using Transpose Split with Vlookup and Importrange - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use the transpose split formula combined with the vlookup importrange values to neatly sort results that turn up with values split by "/" (slash).

Basically, I have a form that needs to be populated from a list of names depending on their roles. In most cases, one name occupies one role, but I do have some roles for which multiple names are present. These are split by an "/" (eg. John Doe/John Smith).

I am new to this and have not managed to wrap my head around what I might be doing wrong. My formula currently reads as follows:

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(B4,{IMPORTRANGE("1_T8NLkWhTDzK6LjxP09mLlphzfLx15FcZeGSdIKZj4M","'BOE''s B.Sc. (Hon) {Inc. ENG Units}'!A1:F");IMPORTRANGE("1_T8NLkWhTDzK6LjxP09mLlphzfLx15FcZeGSdIKZj4M","'BOE''s M.Sc. (Taught)'!A1:F")},4,0))
```

The cell used for this formula is B11 and I would like the second name, when present, to be split and listed in cell B14 (or B12 if that is not possible).

Answer (score 0):

`vLookUp()` will give you just a single value, if I understand you correctly. When the formula you provided is on `B11` and, say, its result value is `John Doe/John Smith`, then you can split it with `/` by `=split(b11, "/")`. Of course it's a horizontal array, so if you want vertical (transposed) result you should use `=transpose(split(b11, "/"))`. Then `B11` will be `John Doe` and `B12` will be `John Smith`.

Comment: Yes exactly. The only problem I have is where should I enter that formula (i.e. transpose(split(b11, "/")) ). I tried adding it to my formula but either it got ignored or it would return errors such as formula parse errors

Comment: I tried my answer and it worked. You'd better provide the sample sheet.